# How do I write a generic method to swap values of items in an array?

Tags: java

I am trying to get this code to work. Most of the code was provided as a question but I just keep getting error after error that I simply to not understand.

```
package generic.collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public static void <T> T swap(Collection<T>, T x, T y) {  
    T temp = a[x]; 
    a[x] = a[y]; 
    a[y] = temp;  
    } 
}
```

Comment: *error after error that I simply to not understand* and we are not mind-readers.  Please explain what problems you are facing.

Comment: Just use `Collections.swap()`

Comment: `a` is a `Collection<T>` not an array. The question is not well defined. What if this `Collection` is a `Set`? What does it mean to swap two elements in a `Set`?

Comment: Where is a defined?

Answer (score 4):

Your definition is off, first a `void` method can't return a `T`. An array is not a `Collection`. And `x` and `y` should be `int`(s). Like,

```
public static <T> void swap(T[] a, int x, int y) {
    T temp = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = temp;
}
```